# hibernate locks row on seperate projects with spring transactional service

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Sorry for title, I couldn't decide how to express the problem.

I have 2 projects which are using same ms sql server database. Both are spring projects and spring is handling transactions.

In one situation first project is creating an entity object then send its id to other project with rest service. Such as:

```
Message message = new Message();
<filling message's properties>
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(message);
String url = <proper url>
MultiValueMap<String, String> mvm = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
mvm.add("id", message.getId());
String response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, mvm, String.class);
message.setStatus("Send to service");
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(message);
```

restTemplate.postForObject successfully sends required data to rest service and service is like follows:

```
Message message = (Message) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Message.class, id);
message.setSendingTime(new Date());
kepMesajDAO.merge(message);
<message process>
```

But the problem is "sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Message.class, id)" metod doesn't return result, actually program is locked there.

I guess hibernate locks my persisted object and second project waits for unlock but since first project is waiting for response from second project it never unlock.

How to handle this situation.

PS. I tried to close or disconnect connection in first project I got exception from spring such as:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:185)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:480)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to commit against JDBC connection
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:116)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:178)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed.
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.checkOpen(PoolingDataSource.java:175)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.commit(PoolingDataSource.java:199)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:112)
        ... 46 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to mostly adhere to your current approach, make sure the first call

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(message);
```

and the second call

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(message);
```

(both being done in the "first project") use a different session. This way hibernate won't lock any rows. Depending on how you use Spring, you may achieve having two sessoins by having two "transactions brackets" in your first project.

Comment: this two calls are on different classes, after save I call a method called sendToRest from different bean and rest of the code is on that method.

Comment: Do you mind extending your question? What strategy did you choose managing your hibernate sessions, i.e. what kind of  CurrentSessionContext is active? Are your sessions associated with a JTA transaction, threadlocal, ...?